# How to keep the neovim terminal buffer in the buffer list even after it being hidden

Tags: neovim, terminal-buffer

My problem is similar to, if not same as, [this issues](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/3340). But I can't follow what they're talking about.

The following steps are necessary to reproduce my problems:

```
:sp
:term
:wincmd w
:wincmd o
:ls
```

And you'll see that the terminal buffer has disappeared. Any idea why it happens and how to keep the terminal buffer present/alive in the buffer list even after it has been hidden?

**Edit** I know about `:set hidden`. But I don't like how it hides buffers yet to be written to disks. I want to use `autocmd` to modify the neovim terminal buffer so that it *can't* be hidden *at all*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put the following in `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`:

```
augroup custom_term
    autocmd!
    autocmd TermOpen * setlocal bufhidden=hide
augroup END
```

I don't know if it's enough, but it is working for now. Check the part with `bufhidden=hide`, this makes only the terminal buffer `hidden` when not loaded on any split/window. I don't know if I have to change any other options like `:h buflisted` or `:h buftype` and thus leaving this post open for anyone to comment.