# How to hide terminal buffer without closing it?

Tags: neovim, terminal, terminal-buffer

I want to make toggleable window with terminal buffer similar to every IDE terminal feature.

---

Currently i have mapped:

```
noremap <F4> :botright 8split term://bash<CR>
tnoremap <F4> <C-\><C-n>:q<CR>
autocmd BufEnter term://* startinsert | set wfh
```

but buffer is lost whenever is not active on any window (ex. on :q)

---

EDIT
And how to reopen the same buffer whenever it already eixsts instead of creating new one every time?

Comment: duplicate of my own question here https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/19276/how-to-keep-the-neovim-terminal-buffer-in-the-buffer-list-even-after-it-being-hi

Comment: And thanks for `:h wfh`, I didn't think there was something like that built in. Nice one!

Comment: And try to wrap autocmd's in augroup. [Check here for why](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/9459/16280).

Comment: thanks! But `:h terminal` says:  'bufhidden' defaults to "hide", so I didin't try myself

Comment: Oh, it does, doesn't it? But check, after launching nvim with `nvim -u NORC` and opening terminal with `:term` and then check `:set bufhidden?`. I see `bufhidden=`, so not defaults to `hide`. Must be a bug. What do you see? We might need to notify neovim community to edit their help documents!

Comment: As for "How to reopen the same terminal buffer", I would recommend adopting to a workflow where you only need one terminal buffer. If you can, then, you just bind your toggling key to check if any `terminal` buffer exists by checking for "term://" in it's bufname. I will try to provide a complete answer if you want.

Answer (score 3):

Now vim has `:term` built in, not just in neo vim. So you can use that and then to hide it use `CTRL-W :hide`

I got this from `:help terminal` (as suggested in the comments above):

```
You can use CTRL-W :hide to close the terminal window and make the buffer   
hidden, the job keeps running.  The :buffer command can be used to turn the 
current window into a terminal window.  If there are unsaved changes this   
fails, use ! to force, as usual.
```

There's lots of buffer commands (see :help buffer-list) but `:unhide` seems to work nicely for this to bring it back.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/m438lr/quick_openhide_terminal/)
Or use this [gist](https://gist.github.com/shivamashtikar/16a4d7b83b743c9619e29b47a66138e0) directly.

Comment: Can you expand your answer so it's not likely to succumb to link rot?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).